# Posting file Rest Template

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to POST a file through a rest call. The file I am going to POST is an xml file. I am also required to have data in the header for authorization purposes. Through some digging, looks like I am supposed to put these headers and file into a map, which can be passed to the rest template's exchange method. This is my source code

```
public class BaseTest {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private HttpHeaders headers;
    private HttpEntity<String> httpEntity;
    private ResponseEntity<String> statusResponse;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("requester", "test");
        headers.set("Authorization", "Token KqY+VEP3A/Cj");

    @Test
    public void testPost() {
        getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        setHttpEntity(new HttpEntity(getHeaders() ));

        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("file", new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\dt208672\\Desktop\\2104000573.SIM2015060000000000.STMT.980061281_52.xml"));
        try {
            getRestTemplate().exchange("https://test.com/documents", HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, getHeaders()), String.class);
        }catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
            fail("Document not found! Status code " + e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the error below. Not sure what the error means. I think I should be setting the content type to application/xml file since it is an xml file but not sure if other configurations are required. Any suggestions?

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [application/xml]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:810)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:594)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
    at com.digitalplatform.test.DocumentTest.testPost(DocumentTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Edited on 03/16/16 at 9:20 pm PST:
Actually the endpoint is this. Does that mean I have to change the method? I probably want to avoid changing any of the code in the method..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/documents", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, AppConstant.APPLICATION_PDF })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@AuditEventAccess(auditEventAccessSuccess = AppConstant.AUDIT_EVENT_CLASFN_ID_POST_REALTIME_DOCUMENT_SUCCESSFUL, auditEventAccessError = AppConstant.AUDIT_EVENT_CLASFN_ID_POST_REALTIME_DOCUMENT_FAILED)
public <T> T postRealTimeDocument(final HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Comment: As the error message says, `no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap]`, Spring does not know how to convert the map object into a string for transfer.  You are probably going to have to read the file contents into a serializable object and then send that as the message body.

Comment: Will the message body be able to deserialize the serialized object?

Answer (score 1):

The problem hear is that you are posting a file and not a string in xml format. For this reason you should make the call as a multipart/form-data.

In practis the your methods should become like below

```
public class BaseTest {

// as your test
    ....

    @Test
    public void testPost() {
        getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        setHttpEntity(new HttpEntity(getHeaders() ));

        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("file", new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\dt208672\\Desktop\\2104000573.SIM2015060000000000.STMT.980061281_52.xml"));
        try {
            getRestTemplate().exchange("https://test.com/documents", HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, getHeaders()), String.class);
        }catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
            fail("Document not found! Status code " + e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}
```

the 400 error is caused because the your client perform a mutlipart request but the your endpoint isn't configured for this propouse 
I use every time that I tract file an endpoint like this:

using Apache Commons FileUpload

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/documents", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity saveDocument(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
       ...
    }
```

or using the Servlet 3 abstraction

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/documents", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity saveDocument(@RequestParam("file") Part file){
       ...
    }
```

or using a dto approach

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/documents", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity saveSocument(@ModelAttribute("file") FileDTO file){
       ...
    }

@Data
class FileDTO {

    private MultipartFile file;
        // eventualy other proeprties

    ....
}
```

Even if you use the standard MultipartFile Spring abstraction, Servlet 3 Part abstraction eigther use a dto like FileDTO, the key point was: use multipart/form-data as consumer mediaType, having Apache commons fileupload or a servlet 3 enviroment

I hope that tihi can help you

Comment: I am getting a 400 Bad Request Error instead

Comment: ok I don't know how your endpoint is written but I expect a think like this:     @RequestMapping(value = "/documents", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")

Comment: public ResponseEntity saveDocument(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)

Comment: Actually the end point is a little different. Not sure if that changes anything. updated question